# Monitoring file changes in linux, Looking for a specific line

Tags: linux, inotifywait, file-monitoring, fswatch, minicom

Assume a linux system with 4 instances of minicom opened and reading serial data input from 4 devices. Each minicom instance is saving the log into the corresponding text file. Serial data is received triggered by specific phisycal events and each event's data packet consists of a header, a footer, and couple of data lines in between:

```
[timestamp] header
[timestamp] data
[timestamp] data
...
[timestamp] data
[timestamp] footer

[timestamp] header
[timestamp] data
[timestamp] data
...
[timestamp] data
[timestamp] footer
```

My goal is to monitor the four log files, and each time a file is modified (by minicom) and as soon as the ***footer*** line is seen at the end of the file, run some scripts. I tried to use **fswatch** and **inotifywait** fot this.

### The problems

The rate in which data lines are received in minicom is approximately 6~7 milliseconds. But I don't want fswatch to print a notification for each line. I just want one notification per packet.

Also the number of log lines (hence the time elapsed from beginning to end of a log packet) vary randomly in each event. So it's not possible to set the `latency` option in fswatch to a constant value and capture each packet with only one notification.

So I guess the only way is to monitor each line added to the files and check for the ***footer*** or ***header*** and then notify the scripts. But I don't know how to do that.

Any advice or suggestions?

### Edit 1

Maybe using `tail -n 1 logfile` after each fswatch notification and comparing it with `"footer"` value?

### Edit 2

Ok. I found this command in the fswatch manpage:

```
fswatch -0 logfile.log | xargs -0 -I {} script.sh
```

and here is the `script.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
footer='packet end'
newline=$(tail -n 1 $HOME/slave.log | grep "$footer")
if [ "$newline" != "" ];
then
    echo "found"
fi
```

It works when the last line is not the *footer*, but as soon as I run `echo "packet end" >> logfile.log` the scripts goes into an infinite loop and keeps printing `found`.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this script using ***inotifywait***:

```
#!/bin/sh
footer='packet end'
portname='port1'
while inotifywait -qq -e modify $HOME/log/"$portname".log; do
    newline=$(tail -n1 $HOME/log/"$portname".log | grep "$footer")
    if [ "$newline" != "" ]; then
        echo 'packet from port1'
    fi
done
```

By running 4 of these scripts for each serial input I'm able to capture the `packet end` line and run other commands.

```
#!/bin/sh
sh port1.sh &
sh port2.sh &
sh port3.sh &
sh port4.sh &
```

Although occasionally some packets are missed, but that's not so bad.

If anybody knows a better way of doing this please post your answer.